# Why my app crashes on Win XP unless i install VS2005 runtime?

Tags: visual-c++, access-violation

I'm trying to investigate why would my app, written in VC 2008, crash on **bare** Windows XP with c0000005. It works great on any windows vista and 7. On XP it would crash with no additional info. Below are the details and the result of a few days worth of my headaches, eliminating one reason after another. Here's the details:

- I have Win7 ultimate with XP Mode with iexplore 6 and presumably no patches whatsoever.
- I install my program and nothing else, since it is supposed to be install-and-run thing with no additional packages needed.
- My app has compiled-in VC2008 runtime (using /MT, as opposed to /MD compiler switch)
- I'm using firebird embedded, which needs **VC2005** *(edited, i wrote VC2008 before)* libs for itself anyway, so i put them in my app's working dir
- when i install VC++ 2008 on this XP Mode machine, it doesn't crash anymore, so debugging this way is impossible
- I've narrowed this error's occurence down to the VC2005 runtime - right after i install it my app stops crashing. But i don't know what could be using it's components. When running the release version under VC2008 IDE, nothing shows any vc2005 libs being loaded (weird, if i say so myself).

My app's linker's dependencies lists these (i added only the first two, the rest was there courtesy of VisualStudio): jpeg.lib, gdiplus.lib, kernel32.lib, user32.lib, gdi32.lib, winspool.lib, comdlg32.lib, advapi32.lib, shell32.lib, ole32.lib, oleaut32.lib, uuid.lib, odbc32.lib, odbccp32.lib, comctl32.lib, %(AdditionalDependencies)

I am also using IBPP firebird interface, which loads these dynamically, so they are present in my app's dir (they need msvc?80.dlls):
fbembed.dll, ib_util.dll, icudt30.dll, icuin30.dll, icuuc30.dll, msvcp80.dll, msvcr80.dll

Please advise why would vc2005 runtime be a remedy for my app to not crash on a bare Win XP. Or how could i debug that one without installing vc 2008 on target machine. I'm starting to blame windows xp's components. Ultimately i want my app to not require any additional packages, such as VC2008 or 2005, especially when no component of my app requires the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am also using IBPP firebird interface ... msvcp80.dll, msvcr80.dll

The answer is in your question, these DLLs are VS2005 runtime support DLLs.  They cannot be stored in your exe directory, they must be registered in the side-by-side cache.  This does not typically cause an AV, but it isn't impossible if the code doesn't check the return value of LoadLibrary().  You can download an installer for them [from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=3387).  It doesn't otherwise have anything to do with Windows XP, you just happened to try to run this program on machines that already had the DLLs installed.  Very common on a dev machine for example.

If you don't want a dependency on them then you'll have to rebuild those DLLs that require it.  Which is a good idea, having a dependency on more than one version of the CRT is pretty unhealthy.

If you are wondering why you are having to deal with this: it was Microsoft's attempt to put DLL Hell in the developer's lap instead of the user's.  They've since withdrawn this, VS2010 again makes it a user problem.  That was a pretty big party in Bangalore, I'd imagine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please elaborate on this unhealthiness you write about - in one of my projects I'm using both oracle OCI built with VC2008 and firebird libs built with VC2005. (Btw, these two VC2005 libs are included along with some manifest in the Firebird embedded package, technically it is not I, who put them in my exe directory). Am I to understand that i should be caring how dlls used by various database providers are built? Can't really do anything about it, and i really don't want to rebuild their client dlls... What's the worst that could happen in this situation?

Comment: A crash or memory leak.  Like an api function that returns an std::string.  Allocated in one CRT, released in another.  That's a kaboom or a leak, depending on the Windows version.  Designing an API that doesn't has this problem must be done carefully.  Basic rule is that it cannot allocate objects or memory that must be deleted or freed by the caller.